# How to find the relevant stylesheet for a specific CSS code

Tags: css, stylesheet

I am having trouble figuring out how to adjust a specific section of a page because I don't know which stylesheet to start with. Do I normally have to open every single stylesheet that the page references and manually search ?

The section involved is a div section with a class name of `widget-content clearfix`.

What's the best way to track the stylesheet that has this div?

---

Thanks a lot guys! I finally figured it out. Took me a while to familiarize with Firebug but I realized it was actually very easy.

Comment: use **FireBug**. You can inspect elements and from the links to the CSS, you can find the relevent CSS

Comment: What browser are you using? - *Firefox* - look for the 'firebug' addon. *Chrome* - `Tools / developer tools` - both give you the ability to 'inspect element' ( point and click ) - it gives you the style for the element, the css file and the line number

Comment: @Era there is nothing much to learn :).
Chrome also have something like firebug, but doesn't have much experiance with that.

Comment: @RobSedgwick thanks! I had one installed and I finally have one of the best CSS tools ever.

Comment: @Ravindu Thanks! It took me a while to get familiar with the tool features but finally got it.

Comment: @SandyAAJ nice to hear that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of right click on web page.
Click on inspect element option.
I have attached one image that show the detail..
[image]

Comment: super thanks for being detailed. I finally figured it out. :)

Comment: if you find all ready solution ...then make comment in your quetion.